# Context bibliography formatting problem

Tags: bibliographies, context

In the bibliography produced by Context MKIV the pages are suddenly in parentheses, but it was not like that a week ago.

```
\setuplanguage[en]
%\setupbackend[export=yes]
\mainlanguage[english]

\startbuffer[bib]

@Book{Declercq:2000,
  author      = {Declercq, Georges},
  title       = {Anno Domini: The origins of the Christian era},
  address     = {Turnhout},
  publisher   = {Brill},
  year        = {2000},
  shorttitle = {Anno Domini},
  shorthand = {Declercq},
  language    = {english},
  hyphenation = {english},
  pagetotal   = {206},
}

@Book{Rupke:2011,
author = {Jörg Rupke},
title = {The Roman Calendar from Numa to Constantine: Time, History, and the Fasti},
address = {Chichester, West Sussex, U.K.},
publisher = {Wiley-Blackwell},
year = {2011},
shorttitle = {The Roman Calendar},
shorthand = {The Roman calendar},
language = {english},
hyphenation = {english},
}

@Incollection{Bloch:2012,
author = {Yigal Bloch},
title = {Middle Assyrian Lunar Calendar and Chronology},
book = {Living the Lunar Calendar},
editor = {J. Ben-Dov},
address = {Oxford},
publisher = {Oxbow},
year = {2012},
pages = {47–48},
language = {english},
hyphenation = {english},
} 

\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[default][bib.buffer]
\loadbtxdefinitionfile[apa]
\usebtxdefinitions[apa]
\setupbtx[dataset=default]
\definebtxrendering[default][apa][specification=chicago,sorttype=authoryear,numbering=no]
\setupindenting[big,yes]
\usetypescript[palatino]
\setupbodyfont[palatino,12pt]

\setupnarrower[left=1cm,right=3cm]

\definehighlight[mysmall][style=small]
\definehighlight[myitalic][style=italic]

\definestartstop
  [abstract][style=italic]
 [before={\midaligned{\bf Abstract}
            \startnarrower[left,right]\mysmall\myitalic},
   after={\stopnarrower
          \blank[big]}]

\startnarrower[2*middle]

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\starttext

\startabstract

\stopabstract

\startbodymatter

Test.\cite[righttext={p.~47}][Bloch:2012] 

\stopbodymatter

\startbackmatter
\startchapter[title=Bibliography]
\placelistofpublications[criterium=all]
\stopchapter
\stopbackmatter

\stoptext
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. You should report it on the [context mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context)