# Display book page number in ConTeXt APA style bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, context

I am using APA style for my bibliographies (better covering of `@film` entries than APS). In French humanistic bibliographies, the page number of a book is often required.

I saw on [this TEX S.E post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480752/context-bibliography-formatting-problem) a .bib example with some `pagetotal` field, which surprised me, since this one is not documented in Hans Hagen's and Alan Braslau's "The bibliographies. The ConTeXt way". Anyway, this field is not displayed on my biblios.

How can I tune the APA style to have it displayed? I read the custom rendering chapter of the docs, but couldn't get how to have it done.

```
\setuppapersize[S4]
\mainlanguage[fr]
\language[fr]

\startbuffer[bib]

@book{Manuel5,
   editor = {Martin Ivernel and Benjamin Villemagne and Jean Hubac},
   title = {Histoire Géographie EMC 5\high{ème}, cycle 4},
   publisher = {Hatier},
   address = {Paris},
   year = {2016},
   pagetotal = {398},
   language = {french}
}
@book{Buhrer-Thierry,
   author = {Geneviève Bührer-Thierry},
   title = {L’Europe carolingienne (714--888)},
   publisher = {SEDES},
   address = {Paris},
   year = {1999},
   pagetotal = {192},
   language = {french}
}
@book{ExpoReich,
        editor = {Matthias Puhle and Claus-Peter Hasse},
        title = {Heiliges Römisches Reich Deutscher Nation 962--1806},
        subtitle = {Von Otto dem Grossen bis zum Ausgang des Mittelalters},
        publisher = {Sandstein Verlag},
        address = {Dresde},
        language = {german},
        pagetotal = {515},
        year = {2006}
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[bib.buffer]
\definebtxrendering
   [biblio]
   [apa]
   [numbering=no,
    sorttype=cite]

\starttext
\nocite[Manuel5]
\nocite[Buhrer-Thierry]
\nocite[ExpoReich]
\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

Comment: You can find all supported fields of `@book` in [`publ-imp-apa.lua`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/64f6e8fc0c6cb9254a6fe3db0b4ab31c51cf8524/tex/context/base/mkiv/publ-imp-apa.lua#L169-L187).

Comment: This means `pagetotal` is not supported, and there is no optional `page` field, as stated in the manual. So is there any way to add such an optional field, or should I write to ConTeXt list to ask for it?

Comment: You will have to write your own bibstyle. Here is an old thread by me asking how to add an `eprint` field to `@article`.  The answer was, use the `note` field or write your own style. https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2016/086205.html

Comment: Ok, I will use the note field and when I have time, create my own style.

Comment: @Henri Menke. Could you turn your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Henri Menke suggestions, I decided to create my own style, which follows the iso690 specifications. I will submit this module within a few days. 
Here I'll just give the steps needed to add pages.

Let's call a `mydefault` style which just changes default style to add pages for books and has only book entries. I have to create two files in your `$TEXMFHOME/tex/context/`, namely `publ-imp-mydefault.lua` and `p-publ-imp-mydefault.mkiv` (I want to load this style as a private module). To keep this example as minimal as possible, I stripped the default style of anything connected to article and citations.

Here is the publ-imp-mydefault.lua. The only change (apart from stripping) to default style is that I added a `"pages"` field in book.

```
return {
    -- derived (combinations of) fields (all share the same default set)
    --
    virtual = {
        "authoryear",
        "authoryears",
        "authornum",
        "num",
        "suffix",
    },
    --
    -- special datatypes
    --
    types = {
        author   = "author",     -- interpreted as name(s)
        editor   = "author",     -- interpreted as name(s)
        page     = "pagenumber", -- number or range: f--t -- maybe just range
        pages    = "pagenumber", -- number or range: f--t -- maybe just range
        volume   = "range",      -- number or range: f--t
        number   = "range",      -- number or range: f--t
        keywords = "keyword",    -- comma|-|separated list
    },
    --
    -- categories with their specific fields
    --
    categories = {
        book = {
            sets = {
                author     = { "author", "editor", },
                editionset = { "edition", "volume", "number" },
            },
            required = {
                "title",
                "year",
            },
            optional = {
                "author", -- a set
                "subtitle",
                "keywords",
                "publisher", "address",
                "editionset",
                "note",
                "pages",
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Here is the p-publ-imp-mydefault.mkiv

```
\startbtxrenderingdefinitions[mydefault]

\definebtxrendering
  [mydefault]
  [\c!specification=mydefault,
   \c!sorttype=\v!default,
   \c!numbering=num]

\setupbtxlist
  [default]
  [\c!align={normal,verytolerant,stretch}]

\definebtx
  [mydefault]
  [\c!default=, % we do not want to fall|-|back on ourself.
   \c!otherstext={\btxspace\btxlabeltext{mydefault:others}},
   %c!journalconversion=\v!normal,
   \c!monthconversion=\v!number,
   \c!separator:names:2={\btxcomma},
   \c!separator:names:3={\btxspace\btxlabeltext{mydefault:and}\space},
   \c!separator:names:4={\btxspace\btxlabeltext{mydefault:and}\space}]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list]
  [mydefault]
  [\c!authorconversion=normalshort]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:\s!page]
  [mydefault:\s!list]
  [\c!separator:2={\btxcomma},
   \c!separator:3={\btxcomma\btxlabeltext{mydefault:and}\space},
   \c!separator:4={\btxspace\btxlabeltext{mydefault:and}\space},
   \c!left={\btxleftparenthesis},
   \c!right={\btxrightparenthesis}]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering]
  [mydefault:\s!list]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering:default]
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering:num]
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering:short]
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering:num]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering:tag]
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering:num]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering:index]
  [mydefault:\s!list:numbering:num]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:author]
  [mydefault:\s!list]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:editor]
  [mydefault:\s!list:author]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:short]
  [mydefault:\s!list]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:title]
  [mydefault:\s!list]
  [\c!style=\v!italic,
   \c!command=\Word]

\definebtx
  [mydefault:\s!list:title:book]
  [mydefault:\s!list:title]

% First some helpers:

\starttexdefinition btx:mydefault:composed-title
    \begingroup
        \language[\currentbtxlanguage]
        \btxflush{title}
        \btxdoif {subtitle} {
            \btxcolon
            \btxflush{subtitle}
        }
    \endgroup
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition btx:mydefault:title
    \btxdoif {title} {
        \btxspace
        \btxstartstyleandcolor [default:list:title:\currentbtxcategory]
            \btxusecommand [default:list:title:\currentbtxcategory] {
                \texdefinition{btx:mydefault:composed-title}
            }
        \btxstopstyleandcolor
        \btxcomma
    }
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition btx:mydefault:author
    \btxdoif {author} {
        \btxflush{author}
        \doif {\btxfoundname{author}} {editor} {
            \btxcomma
            \btxsingularorplural {editor} {
                \btxlabeltext{mydefault:Editor}
            } {
                \btxlabeltext{mydefault:Editors}
            }
        }
        \btxcomma
    }
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition btx:mydefault:year
    \btxflush{year}
    \btxflushsuffix
    \btxcomma
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition btx:mydefault:editionset
    \btxdoif {editionset} {
        \removeunwantedspaces
        \removepunctuation
        \btxleftparenthesis
        \doif {\btxfoundname{editionset}} {edition} {
            \btxflush{edition}
            \btxspace
            \btxlabeltext{mydefault:edition}
            \btxcomma
        }
        \btxdoif {volume} {
            \btxoneorrange {volume} {
                \btxlabeltext{mydefault:Volume}
            } {
                \btxlabeltext{mydefault:Volumes}
            }
            \btxspace
            \btxflush{volume}
            \btxcomma
        }
        \btxdoifelse {number} {
            \btxlabeltext{mydefault:number}
            \btxspace
            \btxflush{number}
        } {
            \removeunwantedspaces
            \removepunctuation
        }
        \btxrightparenthesiscomma
    }
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition btx:mydefault:publisher
    \btxdoif {publisher} {
        \btxflush{publisher}
        \btxcomma
    }
    \btxdoif {address} {
        \btxflush{address}
        \btxcomma
    }
\stoptexdefinition

\starttexdefinition unexpanded btx:mydefault:pages
    \btxdoif {pages} {
        \btxflush{pages}
        \btxnbsp
        \btxlabeltext{p.}
    }
\stoptexdefinition


% Then a minimal number of setups:

\startsetups btx:mydefault:list:book
    \texdefinition{btx:mydefault:author}
    \texdefinition{btx:mydefault:title}
    \texdefinition{btx:mydefault:editionset}
    \texdefinition{btx:mydefault:publisher}
    \texdefinition{btx:mydefault:year}
    \texdefinition{btx:mydefault:pages}
    \removeunwantedspaces
    \removepunctuation
    \btxperiod
\stopsetups

\stopbtxrenderingdefinitions
```

Differences with default style file are: stripping article and cite stuff. I added one helper:

```
\starttexdefinition unexpanded btx:mydefault:pages
    \btxdoif {pages} {
        \btxflush{pages}
        \btxnbsp
        \btxlabeltext{p.}
    }
\stoptexdefinition
```

which I then add to the `btx:mydefault:list:book` setups.

So now, if I proceed this MWE (I kept just one book in the buffer, all this is long enough)

```
\setuppapersize[S4]
\mainlanguage[fr]
\language[fr]
\usemodule[publ-imp-mydefault]

\startbuffer[bib]

@book{Buhrer-Thierry,
   author = {Geneviève Bührer-Thierry},
   title = {L’Europe carolingienne (714--888)},
   publisher = {SEDES},
   address = {Paris},
   year = {1999},
   pages = {192},
   language = {french}
}
\stopbuffer

\usebtxdataset[bib.buffer]
\usebtxdefinitions [mydefault]

\starttext
\nocite[Buhrer-Thierry]
\placelistofpublications
\stoptext
```

I get:

[image: output. Pages are now at the end of the description list]

The original ConTeXt files `publ-imp-default.lua` and `publ-imp-default.mkvi`code are BSD-licence (if I understood well) and owned by the ConTeXt development group.